# VSCode - Disable Ruby Language Server error display

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-code-server

I have had problems with opening files for various Ruby GEMs whereby the Ruby Language Server registers an error and slides out from the side of the VSCode window covering up the code I am trying to view.

This happens every time you click in the editor window. In the example below, this happens when clicking the `option.rb` editor window.

I have had it happen on my own projects, but usually I see this problem on 3rd party GEM's.

The error messages are not useful for me, because it is not code that I control or need to edit or debug.

Is there a way of turning off the setting that pops out this window?

[image]

```
Initializing Ruby language server...
Lint: executing rubocop -s '/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb' -f json -l...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedChildren')
    at Object.build (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:180892)
    at e.default.analyze (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:276790)
    at analyzeNode (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:179150)
    at n (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:178930)
    at n (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:178982)
    at n (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:178982)
    at n (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:178982)
    at n (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:178982)
    at analyze (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:179040)
    at e.project (/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/rebornix.ruby-0.28.1/dist/server/index.js:16:179495)
[Error - 7:36:54 AM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentSymbols')
  Code: -32603 
Lint: executing rubocop -s '/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb' -f json -l...
[Error - 7:36:54 AM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/foldingRange failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foldingRanges')
  Code: -32603 
/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/'/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb': Warning: no department given for AssignmentInCondition.

Lint: executing rubocop -s '/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb' -f json -l...
[Error - 7:37:04 AM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentSymbols')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 7:37:04 AM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/foldingRange failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foldingRanges')
  Code: -32603 
/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/'/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb': Warning: no department given for MethodLength.

[Error - 7:37:07 AM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/foldingRange failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foldingRanges')
  Code: -32603 
Lint: executing rubocop -s '/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/option.rb' -f json -l...
[Error - 10:36:32 AM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentSymbols')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:36:32 AM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/foldingRange failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foldingRanges')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:36:42 AM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rootNode')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:38:24 AM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rootNode')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:38:26 AM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rootNode')
  Code: -32603 
Lint: executing rubocop -s '/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/argument.rb' -f json -l...
[Error - 10:40:35 AM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rootNode')
  Code: -32603 
Lint: executing rubocop -s '/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb' -f json -l...
[Error - 10:41:23 AM] Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentSymbol failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'documentSymbols')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:41:23 AM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/foldingRange failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foldingRanges')
  Code: -32603 
/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/'/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb': Warning: no department given for ClassLength.

/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/'/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb': Warning: no department given for MethodLength.

/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/'/Users/xxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb': Warning: no department given for AssignmentInCondition.

[Error - 10:42:29 AM] Request textDocument/foldingRange failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/foldingRange failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foldingRanges')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:42:31 AM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rootNode')
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:42:48 AM] Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentHighlight failed with message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rootNode')
  Code: -32603
```